# Creating reuseable variables within a .on() or any object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

Sometimes I run into situations where I'm having to *create the same variables*, and retrieve the exact same type of information **over & over again** while inside of a object literal, such as an **`.on()`** Out of sheer curiosity, and the fact that there has to be a better way, here I am.

**NOTE** I am *not* talking about jQuery `.data()` or any sort of normal `window.` global variable. I am talking one that is maintained within the closure of the object literal.

Some of these variables **change in real-time** of course, hence why I always had them inside of each method within `.on()`

Case in point:

```
$(document).on({
    focusin: function () {
        var placeHolder = $(this).attr('data-title'),
            status      = $(this).attr('data-status');
        // etc etc
    },
    focusout: function () {
        var placeHolder = $(this).attr('data-title'),
            status      = $(this).attr('data-status');
        // etc etc
    },
    mouseenter: function () {
        // same variables
    },
    mouseleave: function () { }
}, '.selector');
```

**Is there a way to just have the variables stored somewhere, and retrieve on each event? They need to be dynamic**

```
$(document).on({
     // Basially:

     // var placeHolder; etc
     // each event gets these values

     focusin: function () {
         // now here I can simply use them
         if (placeHolder === 'blahblah') {} 
         // etc
     }
}, '.selector');
```

Comment: Do these attributes change? Do you always need to get the most recent value of them?

Comment: Some of them won't change, but others will, like `status` and other random ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*event data*](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) to pass some static variables to the event, as well as to make a method-wise trick to pass the "dynamic" ones:

```
$(document).on({
    focusin: function(e) {
        var attrs = e.data.getAttributes($(this)),
            var1 = e.data.var1;

        var placeHolder = attrs.title,
            status = attrs.status;
        // ...
    },
    focusout: function(e) {
        var attrs = e.data.getAttributes($(this)),
            var1 = e.data.var1;

        var placeHolder = attrs.title,
            status = attrs.status;
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}, ".selector", {
    // static variables
    var1: "some static value",

    // dynamic "variables"
    getAttributes: function($this) {
        return {
            title: $this.data("title"),
            status: $this.data("status")
        };
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LHPLJ/

Comment: This answer is 100% correct - but it's encouraging non-sensical methodology. Why create event data that contains a function when you can just do $(this).data('title') inside the event? Going through the trouble of creating a new function when already existing ones will do is the counter of trying to optimize.

Comment: @Adam Agree, but the current idea is just to shorten the code length. Anyway the real-time data should be captured per event, so I see no other options for that.

Comment: Incredible! I completely overlooked the data aspect of `.on()`!! This is exactly what I need. I suppose the easiest thing would be then for all the global variables just at the start of each method, call some func `createGlobalVariables(e)` which I could get to return an { title : 'whatever' , status : true } etc

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Yep, something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

1. Write your own function that will return the JSON above; you can loop through properties to keep from duplicating work.
2. Write a function that returns those variables (eg: as JSON) so you need only call one function each time.
3. Write a function to set those variables as global properties and refer to them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add a helper function to extract it?

```
var getData = function(elm) {
    return { 
      placeHolder : $(elm).attr('data-title'),
      status : $(elm).attr('data-status');
  };
};


$(document).on({
  focusin: function () {
    var data = getData (this);
    // do stuff with data.status etc.
  },
  //repeat...
```

Comment: Very nice, so basically the same concept as using the data within the `.on()`. I like it, I also was thinking of doing the same thing regardless, saving all the data into a variable at the start of each function. +1 my man

Answer (score 0):

If you're always targeting the same element (i.e. if there's a single element with class `selector`), and if the values of those variables won't change between the different times the events are triggered, you can store them on the same scope where the handlers are defined:

```
var placeHolder = $('.selector').attr('data-title'),
    status      = $('.selector').attr('data-status');

$(document).on({
    focusin: function () {
        // etc etc
    },
    focusout: function () {
        // etc etc
    },
    mouseenter: function () {
        // same variables
    },
    mouseleave: function () { }
}, '.selector');
```

Functions declared on the same scope as those variables will have access to them.

Comment: It would be `document` instead of `this` in this instance.

Comment: @VisioN, I was thinking about targeting the same element every time (but I'm not sure if that's the OP is looking for). Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @bfavaretto, is there anyway I can get the variable to basically... re-create itself to get the updated value when entering any section of the `.on()` methods?  As in, it checks to see what the current 'state' is, etc

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping everything in a function scope so that the variables are not global. If these attributes never change, you could do something like:

```
(function(sel){
    var placeHolder = $(sel).attr('data-title'),
        status      = $(sel).attr('data-status');

    $(document).on({
        focusin: function () {
            // etc etc
        },
        focusout: function () {
            // etc etc
        },
        mouseenter: function () {
            // same variables
        },
        mouseleave: function () { }
    }, sel);
})('.selector');
```

Otherwise, you could do this (in modern browsers, IE9+)

```
(function(sel){
    var obj = {};
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'placeHolder', {
        get:function(){return $(sel).attr('data-title');}
    });
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'status', {
        get:function(){return $(sel).attr('data-status');}
    });

    $(document).on({
        focusin: function () {
            console.log(obj.placeHolder, obj.status);
            //etc etc
        },
        focusout: function () {
            // etc etc
        },
        mouseenter: function () {
            // same variables
        },
        mouseleave: function () { }
    }, sel);
})('.selector');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP takes `.attr('data-title')`, *etc* from the *current* `this` element, which was focused, hovered, *etc*. So, if there are multiple `.selector` elements you won't get the proper data.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it close to correct, but the best way to do it is this:

```
$(document).on({
    focusin: function () {
        var el = $(this), //cache the jQ object
            placeHolder = el.data('title'),
            status = el.data('status');
        // etc etc
    }
}, '.selector');
```

Data was created for this purpose, don't worry about trying to create re-useable items. If you're delegating the event using object, then it's probably because the elements aren't always on the page in which case you need to get the variables within each individual event.

Finally, don't try to optimize when you don't need to.

Answer (score -1):

You can save them in the window object and make them global.

`window.yourVariable = "whatever";`

This does what you want but is for sure not the most clean way. If you can, you can consider saving the desired data to the object itself via `$(element).data("key", "value")`